# Something is wrong with large numbers as powers?

Tags: arrays, numpy, math

I am trying to do the inverse of the `np.log10` function. I have a numpy array called `a` with the log10 of some values. However, when I try with `10**a` I get weird numbers, and I get the same result using `np.power(10,a)`. Otherewise, if I try with single numbers like `10**42` it works. Why??

```
    >>> a=np.array([42,43,44])
    >>> a
    array([42, 43, 44])
    >>> 10**a
    array([-6640025486929952768,  7386721425538678784,    80237960548581376])
    >>> 10**a[0]
    -6640025486929952768
    >>> a[0]
    42
    >>> 10**42
    1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Please note that `10**(big number)` is not just a big number, its a **huge** number. I mean really huge. I assure you that you don't really want to compute `10**7386721425538678784`.

Comment: As for `10**-6640025486929952768`, it's not just a small number, it's a **minuscule** number. So minuscule that python rounds it down to `0.0`. So computing `10**-6640025486929952768` is not really useful either.

Comment: @Stef 10**42 is something extremely common in what I do for work, so yes, I really want to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Each numpy data type in has a minimum and maximum value based on the number of bits. From your output, it looks like your array has dtype `np.int64`. You can check out those min/max values using `np.iinfo()`. E.g.

```
a = np.array([42,43,44], dtype = 'int64') 
# You can try leaving the dtype blank 
# and see what the default type is

print(a.dtype)
print(np.iinfo(a.dtype))
```

When you execute `10**a[0]`, Python decides to cast it to 64-bit integer and if the value is over the maximum, then it will crossover from the max value to the min value and keep going from there.

The reason `10**42` works is that Python interprets both values as primitive type `int` which has no fixed memory limit and can have an arbitrary maximum value.

You can do something similar with `10**int(a[0])`, but you can't do this with the whole array.